# Python Webdriver need code to find a particular element

Tags: python, selenium

I have used Python 2.7, Webdriver and Chrome to access Pinterest to insert images to a board. I have successfully logged in to the site, created a board and clicked on the Pin Image button (thanks to Stack Overflow). The problem that I have is to identify and click the “No Thanks” button using xpath find elements code. I attach an image of the web page and the Chrome inspect on the element.

[Pinterest 'Popup'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeEEa.jpg)

[Not Now Element code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkL0K.jpg)

Comment: please paste the code you have tried so far and what error you are getting when running that code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can give a try to this xpath, which will grap the first element containing the class "cancelButton". Hopefully, the button on your popup will be the first element on the page containing this class.

```
button[contains(@class, 'cancelButton')]
```

Comment: Glad for you :) You can thank thebadguy by choosing his answer, so your question will appear as "answered". It might help other users who are facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
//span[contains(text(),'Not now')]
```

this is general syntax: `//tag[contains(attribute,‘value’)]`

Comment: This code also worked for me. It's a little more precise. Thanks